# Node module in Alloy project

Tags: node.js, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I need to put [this](https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk) node.js module into Alloy project. It's a Facebook SDK node module.

I put the install command, and a node_module folder appear into my project folder, but I can't use it.

Where have I to put this node_module folder? Why the requires into facebook.js are not founded by the compiler?

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titanium is not a pure NodeJS environment. When you use `require('test')` in a Titanium Alloy project, it will look for a file named `test.js` in the directory `<Your project>/app/lib/`.

Titanium can't handle a `require` on a directory with a `package.json`.

So if you want a pure `NodeJS` module, you'll have to put every files needed in the `<Your project>/app/lib/` directory.

But keep in mind that you can't use a NodeJS module which depends on NodeJS API like requests, because there's no such things in Titanium (you have to Ti.HttpClient instead).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I only want an alternative to login into Facebook because the titanium module doesn't work for me. But I haven't got alternative.....

Comment: Does `request.js` work with alloy project? I have installed it `User/saif` and copied the file to `app/lib` folder, Is it a correct way to use node modules ?